# My microphone volume is very low

Tags: laptop, 19.04, microphone

I have the newest ubuntu installed with everything up to date. It's a laptop so there's an integrated microphone in it which does work under windows. It's made by Intel. Alsamixer says HDA Intel PHC. I tried to adjust the microphone in alsamixer but it changes nothing and resets everytime i restart the laptop. It can barely record my voice when im speaking next to the mic very loudly.

Comment: Run `alsamixer` and press `F5` to see all the controls. Search if You have one named `Mic Boost` - make sure it is unmuted - set to `00` instead of `MM`.

Comment: It's always muted. If i unmute it nothing happens and becames muted again if i restart the laptop

Comment: Do You have option `Auto-Mute` in `alsamixer` and is it disabled ?

Comment: It's enabled by default. But nothing changes when i disable or enable it

Answer (score 7):

Install `pavucontrol`:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Launch it by running `pavucontrol` on the command-line, and adjust the volume of the mic in the "Input Devices" tab. You can even go above 100%, although I don't recommend it as it can lead to distorted sound:

[image]